# Determine a definite integral knowing that $f$ is even, integrable and such that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \pi$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Assume that $f$ is even, integrable, and such that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \pi$.  Determine the definite integral
>   $$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x) f(\sin x) dx.$$

Since f is even it follows that the given integral is equal to
$$2 \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x) f(\sin(x)) dx.$$
I see that it's possible to write $\cos(x)f(\sin(x))$ as $g'(x)f(g(x))$ but not sure if that's of any use moving forward.

Comment: You did most of the work, just make a change of variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct and you are almost done. If $f$ is even then $g(x):=\cos(x) f(\sin(x)) $ is even too 
$$g(-x)=\cos(-x) f(\sin(-x))=\cos(x) f(-\sin(x))=\cos(x) f(\sin(x))=g(x),$$
and
$$\int_\frac{-\pi}{2}^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x) f(\sin(x)) dx=
2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x) f(\sin(x)) dx=2\int_0^1 f(t) dt=2\pi$$
where we made the change of variable $t=\sin(x)$ with $dt=\cos(x) dx.$ 
Note that as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$ then $t=\sin(x)$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Ah the thing I couldn't figure out was how to get the $\frac{π}{2}$ to a $1$

Comment: @JohnDoe Is it clear now?

Comment: yes thanks a lot!